# In Python, can you declare all available instance variables ahead of time?

Tags: python, class

In Python (I'm talking 2 here, but would be interested to know about 3 too) is there a way to define in advance a list of all instance variables (member fields) you want available i.e. make it an error to use one you've not defined somewhere?

Something like

```
class MyClass(object):
    var somefield
    def __init__ (self):
        self.somefield = 4
        self.banana = 25      # error!
```

A bit like you do in Java, C++, PHP, etc

**Edit:**

The reason I wanted this kind of thing was to spot early on using variables that hadn't been setup initially. It seems that a linter will actually pick these errors up without any extra plumbing so perhaps my question is moot...

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @mattwritescode, Dhara: Using `__slots__` can make the code faster in certain situations. Beyond that, it can enforce certain OOP practices. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots)

Comment: As I understand Python there is no safe way but you could "protect" your variables by writing properties for them and check the existence before you set a variable. I could also think of a redefinition of the set_attr method of an object initiating with a list of "allowed" variables. But this are only short thoughts about this.

Comment: I'd like this as it seems like the kind of thing a linter or compiler could find early on if I declare the list of allowed members up front. Saves any typos, copy-pasta errors, etc before runtime - crash early, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why yes, you can.

```
class MyClass(object):
    __slots__ = ['somefield']
    def __init__ (self):
        self.somefield = 4
        self.banana = 25      # error!
```

But [mind the caveats](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Comment: Simultaneous answer! :) -- But yours has code :(.  I suppose I'll delete mine then ...

Comment: @Dhara why is using slots a bad idea? Seems like it does what I'm after, and presumably a linter would catch these errors early on?

Comment: @Seb: A linter would catch your errors without using `__slots__` too. Conclusion: use a linter instead of abusing `__slots__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters righto, point taken. Maybe I'll spend a bit of time figuring out how to get my linter to work often enough to be useful...!

Comment: I want to post a link to code.activestate with a better solution but I get the error links to <url> not allowed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots explains that using __slots__ in this way would make me a control freak or a static typing weenie. Guess I'll just stick to the linter :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer posted above, but for a more "pythonic" approach, try the method listed at (link to code.activestate.com)

For future reference, and until I can figure out how to link to the website, here's the code:

```
def frozen(set):
    """Raise an error when trying to set an undeclared name, or when calling
       from a method other than Frozen.__init__ or the __init__ method of
       a class derived from Frozen"""
    def set_attr(self,name,value):
        import sys
        if hasattr(self,name):                                  #If attribute already exists, simply set it
            set(self,name,value)
            return
        elif sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name is '__init__':     #Allow __setattr__ calls in __init__ calls of proper object types
            for k,v in sys._getframe(1).f_locals.items():
                if k=="self" and isinstance(v, self.__class__):
                    set(self,name,value)
                    return
        raise AttributeError("You cannot add attributes to %s" % self)
    return set_attr
```

Comment: That's rather clever. But as  Martijn Pieters pointed out, it seems pylint actually picks the kind of errors I was trying to prevent without any extra plumbing. So maybe my question is redundant...